# How to properly place figure in a subsection?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, graphs

I am new to latex. Actually i am using pre defined template for making graphs for my Advanced Algo Course.
Here is my code for drawing graph within a square.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.8, auto,swap]
    % Draw a 7,11 network
    % First we draw the vertices
    \foreach \pos/\name in {{(3,2)/a}, {(2,1)/c}, {(3,1)/b},
                            {(4,1)/d},{(5,1)/e},{(1,0)/f},{(2,0)/g},{(6,0)/h}}
        \node[vertex] (\name) at \pos {$\name$};

    % Connect vertices with edges and draw weights
   \foreach \source/ \dest /\weight/\pos in {c/a,
                                         d/a,
                                         b/a,
                                         e/a,a/c,c/f,c/g,e/h}
        \path[edge] (\source) -- (\dest);
    \draw (0,-0.3) -- (6.4,-0.3) -- (6.4,1.8) -- (0,1.8) -- (0,-0.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}
```

**Problem:**
First Image is where i want to place my graph. And second image is where my graph is being wrongly placed.[image]

[image]

Comment: if you just used `tikzpicture` then the picture would stay where you put it, the only reason to put something in `figure` is to allow latex to move it to help with page breaking, so it's working as designed  but you could use `\begin{figure}[htbp]` to also allow it to try `h` (here)

Comment: In other words, the floats have the  bad habit of floating `:)` Usually is better use the `figure` float because often the alternative  is left ungraceful  half-filled pages when an image does not fit at the end of the page. But you can change a bit  the float's bevhaviour  (see  [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)) and use [cross-references](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing) when is not posiblle place the figures whitin their section.